# In a skeletal muscle contraction, what happens after ACh binds to the nicotinic iontropic receptors on sarcolemma?

Tags: muscles, cell-signaling, receptor

Does the bound ACh becomes unbound and then gets hydrolysed by acetylcholinerase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: acetylcholineesterase]

Acetyl choline, which is released at the neuromuscular junction is continuously broken down by the enzyme acetylcholineesterase into acetate and choline. Choline is once again taken up by the neuron through choline carriers to regenerate acetylcholine. This process continues as long as an the neuron is stimulated.

**Source:**
[Wikepedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetylcholinesterase)

Comment: That's correct, acetylcholineesterase is a hydrolase (An enzyme which hydrolyzes choline esters (Such as Acetylcholine).